# Finding new Java class at runtime

Tags: java

I have a functionality that I wish to provide to a customer for a software mockup that we are preparing - and I want to know if it's

1. possible
2. intelligent (a.k.a. not stupid)
3. the best thing

I want the customer to be able to write a java class that implements my `Computable` interface and stick it in some predetermined folder.  This folder will contain the .java files rather than .class files.  Then, at runtime, I want my program to search that folder and extract all of the `Computables` from that folder and store them in a map from the name of the `Computable` to the `Computable` object.  The `Computable` should only have a default constructor and the it interface will only have one method called `compute` which maps an array of `Object` to an `Object`.

Comment: Do you want to compile the users' files at runtime?

Comment: Does it have to be the language itself, or would another scripting language be OK?

Comment: @jedierikb If it's easy enough to compile at runtime that would be fine.  I just don't want the customer to have to worry about dragging around class files.

Comment: @skaffman Java friendly customer... should probably stick with Java

Comment: Not even a scripting language tied closely to java, such as groovy?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Java Compiler API](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) introduced in Java SE 6 should give you what you need.

Comment: Note that this API is only available in JDK, not in JRE. So if you ever intend to distribute it, the enduser/client must have installed JDK and this is pretty uncommon among the major public.

Comment: @BalusC Does the 'x' at the end of javax always imply this?

Comment: No, it doesn't always. Some are (became) part of standard Java SE API, others aren't.

Answer (score 3):

You may find [Google Reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) useful to find classes implementing/extending a certain interface/superclass in the classpath. It's then as straightforward as

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.project.prefix");
Set<Class<? extends SomeClassOrInterface>> subTypes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(SomeClassOrInterface.class);
```

Then, to test if it indeed has a no-arg default constructor, just check for each if [`Class#newInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) doesn't throw any exception.

Comment: So what if the .class file was not on the current path, but in a folder that we only learn about at runtime?

Comment: You can add paths to the classpath during runtime using [`URLClassLoader`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html).

Answer (score 2):

There are several suggestions provided as answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781805/defining-a-class-while-a-java-application-is-running).

Here too [On-the-fly, in-memory java code compilation for Java 5 and Java 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616532/on-the-fly-in-memory-java-code-compilation-for-java-5-and-java-6)

Answer (score 1):

> If it's easy enough to compile at runtime that would be fine.

You can use [`javax.tools`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/package-summary.html) to do the compilation as needed. [*Create dynamic applications with javax.tools*](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jcomp/index.html) may help, too. It's also possible to do it [in memory](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.programmer/msg/3d0e78934c17a27f).

One caveat: using the compiler creates a dependency on the JDK; the JRE alone is insufficient.

Comment: You have any sample code?  Do I address the command line from Java to execute javac?  How do I think suck in the class file and construct the class?

Answer (score 0):

take a look: [Find Java classes implementing an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435890/find-java-classes-implementing-an-interface)

Comment: Looked promising, but it appears to revolve around two possible solutions. 1) Use an API some guy built for himself (I don't want to risk playing with someone else's framework in the short time I have left.) or 2) Using reflection to figure out which already loaded classes implement `Computable`.  Recall that my classes won't be loaded... they are just .java files.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this would be simpler if you allowed your customer to type in a code declaration using something like Groovy, which is Java-ish enough, and easy to execute at runtime from a String value.

Comment: Isn't Groovy a strict superset?  If so I suppose you could just tell your customer that it's taking Java and they'll be none the wiser.

Comment: Ah, I'm wrong.  A java file is almost always valid groovy code but it's not a strict superset.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy enough to iterate through the list of files in a folder. Someone mentioned that it's possible to call the Java compiler from Java (if you re-distribute the JDK, which I think is a point whose legality needs checking!!) That's much of the battle.

You seem to have a fixed model in your mind where only files fulfilling a certain interface are extracted from the folder. I think this is where your method needs to give a little. The sensible way (IMO) to do this would be to compile *all* files in that folder, and then with their classes stashed away somewhere, you can load and reflect them and then determine which of them "do" the interface and which don't. Those that don't will have been needlessly loaded into your JVM, but unless it's intentionally very space-wasteful, code you don't execute can't harm your program.

Having determined which ones do the computable thing, you can then store those classes (or instances thereof) in a Collection and do whatever you like with them. You simply ignore the other ones.

Answer (score 0):

You could use BeanShell. This library is small and doesn't require the JDK. It is used in a number of IDE and web servers.  The latest version appears to have the support you need loading .java files from the class path.  (Still in beta)