# Java -- object creation "on the fly"

Tags: java, class, object

Is there a way of defining a class "on the fly"-- that is, instantiating an object without an explicit declaration of a class?

What i'm looking for is instantiating an object, using the constructor of **Object** maybe(?), and defining some members (2 literal variables) while doing that.

I need an object-- and one object of that type only-- of 2 literals as members. 
I don't want to define a class to do that. And, as far as i know, Java doesn't have some type like **struct** to do that.

I don't think Java does this-- but still.

Thanks in advance.

Note: i've seen [Does Java support structs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168144/structs-in-java) and [Struct like objects in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36701/struct-like-objects-in-java).

Comment: Nope. Put them into an enum with one member; the extra boilerplate is three lines. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427902

Comment: There are no structs in java.  Perhaps what you want is just an array of size 2, or an `enum`.

Comment: @yshavit this is fine. thx.

Comment: @Steve P. array wd do technically, but doesn't look crafty. thx just the same.

Comment: FYI, the inability to do this succinctly is one reason why you'll see Java spin-offs like Groovy and Scala.

Comment: @Roam I understand where you're coming from, but it doesn't have to be "crafty."  An array of size 2 is probably the best way to go here.  An `enum` would make sense if you wanted to restrict the values that your "object" can take, but otherwise I would just go with an array...If you want to be crafty look into other languages, java is not good for this sort of thing.

Comment: @Paul Draper - dont know abt Groovy and vaguely familiar with Scala. had in mind JavaScript-like thing, this v.probably the same ting UR referring to.

Comment: This thread would be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781805/defining-a-class-while-a-java-application-is-running

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to avoid defining a class?  What's the issue with that?

Comment: @JimN, I think the OP wants the succinctness of something like `{foo:'bar', baz:0}`, like Javascript.

Comment: Ok.  If you're fine with giving up type safety, you might prefer to use a scripting language instead.  But in Java you could do:  Arrays.asList(a, b);

Comment: Instead of creating a new class on the fly, you could save the values in a `Map`.