# Create a java class using its source code as a string

Tags: java, class, annotations, code-generation

assume that I have this String :
and i need to generate a class of it inside another class ?
Kindly any one have a suggestion for this ?**

```
 String sourceCode = "public class Test {   " +
        "public void myMethod(@Mandatory String s){"+
        "System.out.println( \"myMethod : \"+s);}"+


 "@SuppressWarnings(\"unused\")"+
 "private void mySecondMethod(String s2){"+
    "System.out.println(\"mySecondMethod : \"+s2);}"+ 

 "}";
```

Comment: Look at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616532/on-the-fly-in-memory-java-code-compilation-for-java-5-and-java-6

Answer (score 1):

You can generate java classes dynamically using `Java Compiler API`

http://www.accordess.com/wpblog/an-overview-of-java-compilation-api-jsr-199/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [JavaCompiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html).

There are examples in the link.