# Create .java file and compile it to a .class file at runtime

Tags: java, compilation, runtime

I'm generating a whole bunch of .java files from an XSD file using XJC. I also need to compile those files to .class files and use them at runtime via reflection.

The problem I'm having is that after I generate the .java files and try to compile them, the compiler can't compile them properly and gives me the following error:

```
.\src\com\program\data\ClassOne.java:44: error: cannot find symbol
    protected List<ClassTwo> description;
                   ^
  symbol:   class ClassTwo
  location: class ClassOne
```

I'm assuming this has to do with the fact that the JVM doesn't know about the package I just generated and as such can't find the referenced classes.

This can be solved by simply restarting the program after generating the .java files. But I'm curious if there's a way to do both steps during runtime without a restart.

I've looked at ways to "refresh" what packages are on the classpath at runtime, but with no luck.

This is the method I'm using to compile the files.

```
public static void compile(Path javaPath, String[] fileList) {
    for (String fileName : fileList) {
        Path fullPath = Paths.get(javaPath.toString(), fileName);

        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        compiler.run(null, null, null, fullPath.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally figured this out...

Apparently you could pass several files to the compiler at once, and this solves the symbol error. What a stupidly simple solution.

```
public static void compile(String... files) {
    JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
    compiler.run(null, null, null, files);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking up existing threads for the same topic ;
[On-the-fly, in-memory java code compilation for Java 5 and Java 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616532/on-the-fly-in-memory-java-code-compilation-for-java-5-and-java-6?rq=1)

for example.