# Dynamically create and read java classes

Tags: java, class, xsd, runtime, xjc

I am working on a project that creates Java classes from xsd. At run-time, I want to create classes and read names of these classes. However, when I first run the project (before classes are created) it gives me an error that says "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: generated.classes.AddressType" . If I run again , without changing anything (classes are created at this point) , it does not give me an error. I used "com.sun.tools.xjc.api" for creating classes. When I want to read class names, I simply do that

```
File folder = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\generated\\classes");
    File[] listOfFiles = null;
    List<String> namesOfClasses = new ArrayList<>();
    listOfFiles=folder.listFiles();
    for(File file: listOfFiles){
            try {
                    if(!file.getName().equals("ObjectFactory.java")){
                        String classname="generated.classes."+file.getName().substring(0, file.getName().length() - 5);
                        namesOfClasses.add(classname);
                    }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    return namesOfClasses;
```

It seems , new created classes cannot be seen at runtime. How can I make this classes read at runtime?

Comment: I don't see how the shared code can throw `ClassNotFoundException`. As reading class names from the directory has nothing to do with class loading.

Comment: Here is the code: [http://pastebin.com/yeHkcMxq](http://pastebin.com/yeHkcMxq)

Comment: My guess - your code generates `.java` files and we need `.class` to load a class. I'm guessing you are using an IDE have the automatic build on or something that's how your program is picking the `class` files in the next run.

Answer (score 0):

You may compile your classes on the fly like ([by answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30912479/create-java-file-and-compile-it-to-a-class-file-at-runtime/33045582#33045582)):

```java
    JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
    compiler.run(null, null, null, files);
```

Please look at similar questions for other alternatives:

- [Create .java file and compile it to a .class file at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30912479/create-java-file-and-compile-it-to-a-class-file-at-runtime/33045582#33045582)
- [On-the-fly, in-memory java code compilation for Java 5 and Java 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616532/on-the-fly-in-memory-java-code-compilation-for-java-5-and-java-6?rq=1)
- [A Java API to generate Java source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121324/a-java-api-to-generate-java-source-files/122209#122209)

And I do exactly that in test of my [xjc-documentation-annotation-plugin](https://github.com/Hubbitus/xjc-documentation-annotation-plugin)
: [XJCPluginDescriptionAnnotationTest](https://github.com/Hubbitus/xjc-documentation-annotation-plugin/blob/master/src/test/groovy/info/hubbitus/XJCPluginDescriptionAnnotationTest.groovy#L80) it may be used as step-by-step tutorial.